# Can I modify the total number of pages in multi-page tiff?

Tags: tiff, libtiff

I am receiving data from a camera and saving each image as a page in a multi-page tiff. I can set that each file has e.g. 100 pages and I am calling:

`TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_PAGENUMBER, page_number, total_pages);`

However, if I am unable to write data to disk fast enough, I will stop the acquisition. At this point I may have written 50 out of 100 pages into a multi-page tiff. Now the multi-page tiff file reports total number of pages as 100, but only 50 pages have been actually written. Some applications will report 100 pages, but for pages 51-100 there will be no data and images will appear to be black.

Therefore I would need to update the `total_pages` number at the moment when I am ending the disk writing to the value of the last written page.
Can this be done at all? Is the `total_pages` value written once into a common header which I could update and fix the file in this way, or is this value written into each page which means I would have to edit each page that has already been written to disk? Or is there any better approach how to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the solution is quite simple. 
Once your image stream has ended and before you close the file, you have to iterate through all the directories (images in the multi-page tiff) and update the `TIFFTAG_PAGENUMBER` to the total pages written. 
The catch is you have to do it before you close the tiff by calling `TIFFClose`. Once a TIFF is closed, its TAGS cannot be edited anymore. (see http://www.libtiff.org/libtiff.html):

*Note that unlike the stdio library TIFF image files may not be opened for both reading and writing; there is no support for altering the contents of a TIFF file.*

```
if (pagesTotal - pagesWritten > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < pagesWritten; i++)
    {
         int retVal = TIFFSetDirectory(out, i);
         retVal = TIFFSetField(out, TIFFTAG_PAGENUMBER, i, pagesWritten);
         retVal = TIFFWriteDirectory(out);
     }
}
TIFFClose(out);
```

`pagesTotal` is number of pages that we inteded to write into this multi-page file

`pagesWritten` is number of pages that we actually wrote into the file